# can not get scion_server to be created using runghc

Tags: eclipse, haskell, cabal

I downloaded the scion cabal and am attempting to created scion_server

I ran all of the runghc Setup (configure/build/install)

The Haskell libraries are installed, but the scion_server is not in the ~/.cabal/bin

I have to use a --user on configure so I can install it on just my account.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem when doing a verbose on configure.

The server option by default was set to False.

When I did

```
runghc Setup configure --flags="server"
```

I was able to get the server file

Answer (score 1):

Try unregistering the scion package with GHC and reinstalling it again. (That usually fixes these kinds of issues for me.)

```
~/scion $ ghc-pkg unregister scion
~/scion $ cabal install
```

Note that `cabal install` in the proper directory is the same as "configure --user/build/install".